# Prevent firefox from trying to download images instead of viewing them?

Tags: firefox, images, download

Sometimes when I right click -> view image on a picture on a website (often gifs) firefox will try to download the file instead of viewing it in a new tab.  Is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, go to Options -> Applications tab. If .GIF is in the list of file types there, change the preference to "Always ask."

If that doesn't do it, go into Windows Control Panel -> Default Programs -> Set Associations. Make Firefox the default program for opening .GIFs. I think Internet Explorer or Windows Explorer handles .GIFs by default, which would explain why they are being downloaded to your file system and not Firefox's temp folder.

If that is also a dead end, see if you've got an Add-On affecting the way .GIFs or other images are treated in Firefox. Disable the relevant Add-Ons or start Firefox in safe mode and see if the problem continues.